# PHP Phone Regex - Don't exceed length of 8 numbers

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a phone regex.

```
$regexNumber = '#^[1-9][0-9]{8}$#';
```

As for now it's saying that the first number should start with 1-9 while the following numbers should be between 0-9.

The issue appears when I want to control that the phone number doesn't exceed the length of 8 numbers. I thought the curly braces would solve my issue but I might be using them wrong. I am hoping that one of reading my post could enlighten me.

Thank you alot in advance.

Comment: So, you want to allow one up to 8 digits? `'#^[1-9][0-9]{0,7}$#'`?

Comment: @wiktorStribizew I would like to allow there only to be 8 digits. Nothing more, nothing less. eg. '10203040'

Comment: So, `[1-9]` is 1 digit, 7 remains, right? Use `'#^[1-9][0-9]{7}$#'`.

Comment: The curly braces _would_ solve your problem, once you realize that you want to match only _seven_ characters out of that class, because you matched a single one with `[1-9]` before that already ...

Comment: Oh wow. Sometimes it's the most obvious which lies ahead of you. Thank you very much you two.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```php
$regexNumber = '#^(?!0)\d{8}$#';
```

This is simple and clear: 8 digits but no `0` at the start.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/JGKRVz/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0                        '0'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{8}                    digits (0-9) (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```